# C# implementation of Dictionary to count occurrences of words returns duplicate words in output

Tags: c#, dictionary, counter

I recently made a little application to read in a text file of lyrics, then use a Dictionary to calculate how many times each word occurs. However, for some reason I'm finding instances in the output where the same word occurs multiple times with a tally of 1, instead of being added onto the original tally of the word. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
StreamReader input = new StreamReader(path);
        String[] contents = input.ReadToEnd()
                                            .ToLower()
                                            .Replace(",","")
                                            .Replace("(","")
                                            .Replace(")", "")
                                            .Replace(".","")
                                            .Split(' ');
        input.Close();
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (String word in contents)
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                dict[word]++;
            }else{
                dict[word] = 1;
            }
        }
        var ordered = from k in dict.Keys
                              orderby dict[k] descending
                              select k;
        using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
        {
            foreach (String k in ordered)
            {
                output.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", k, dict[k]));
            }
            output.Close();
            timer.Stop();
        }
```

The text file I'm inputting is here: http://pastebin.com/xZBHkjGt (it's the lyrics of the top 15 rap songs, if you're curious)
The output can be found here: http://pastebin.com/DftANNkE
A quick ctrl-F shows that "girl" occurs at least 13 different times in the output. As far as I can tell, it is the exact same word, unless there's some sort of difference in ASCII values. Yes, there are some instances on there with odd characters in place of a apostrophe, but I'll worry about those later. My priority is figuring out why the exact same word is being counted 13 different times as different words. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way is to split on non words.

```
var lyrics = "I fly with the stars in the skies I am no longer tryin' to survive I believe that life is a prize But to live doesn't mean your alive Don't worry bout me and who I fire I get what I desire, It's my empire And yes I call the shots".ToLower();
var contents = Regex.Split(lyrics, @"[^\w'+]");
```

Also here's an alternative (and probably more obscure) loop

```
int value;
foreach (var word in contents)
{
    dict[word] = dict.TryGetValue(word, out value) ? ++value : 1; 
}
dict.Remove("");
```

Comment: Regex was considered, but I had no idea as to what the proper pattern would be. That worked like a charm, the only issue is that the first ranked word is blank with over 1800 occurrences. Not sure how to resolve that, but I'll figure it out. Thank you!
Also, That loop does seem obscure. In my researching for a counting loop I never saw anything like that. Makes perfect sense though. Much nicer and apparently time efficient too, I think I'll stick with that. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, that's odd. When I gave it a much larger text document, the previous loop was actually faster. Not that a few hundred milliseconds matters at all, just found it interesting.
Edit: Okay, and now it's not. That's peculiar. Haha, oh well. Just find execution time/efficiency interesting :]

Comment: Added removal of empty strings. It's pity that `Regex.Split` doesn't have a `RemoveEmptyEntries` option like the `String.Split` has.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yeah that'd be helpful for it to have that as well. That's pretty cool how that little bit has tied two separate answers together, hah. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

If you notice, the repeat occurrences appear on a line following a word which apparently doesn't have a count.

You're not stripping out newlines, so `em\r\ngirl` is being treated as a different word.

Comment: Oh duh. I was thinking about newlines, but for some reason assumed they wouldn't be a problem. Thank you!

Also, my apologies for not selecting your response as the answer. You certainly had the right answer for me to figure out how to solve it myself without just giving me the code, so I really appreciate that! Just figured for those stopping by the question to find an answer, code examples would benefit them.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] contents = input.ReadToEnd()
    .ToLower()
    .Replace(",", "")
    .Replace("(", "")
    .Replace(")", "")
    .Replace(".", "")
    .Split("\r\n ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Works better.

Comment: And the last word on the list of most used words in 15 rap lyrics is "reality"!

Comment: Hmm, for some reason this is giving me twenty or so more words than other answers. Other than that, solves my problem, thanks a lot!
Out of curiosity, why is the newline string made into a char array?
I was also unaware of StringSplitOptions, that's certainly good to know.
Haha, I just saw that now. I think that's mainly due to it's occurrence in the last song, as there are plenty of words with only 1 occurrence. Funny, though!

Comment: Split doesn't take a string, it takes an array of chars. I would put all kinds of whitespace in that string so the split would use all of them. You could even put commas and parenthesis in it, instead of using Replace. I just wanted to make the smalles possible change in your code to show you how close you really were. :-)

Comment: Oh wow. I totally forgot it takes in chars, not strings. Never knew it could take in an array, though. I was actually just thinking to myself how I should write a method to take in an array of strings and iterate through it to do multiple replace/removals. Guess that isn't needed. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Add `Trim` to each word:

```
foreach (String word in contents.Select(w => w.Trim()))
```

Comment: Didn't even know that method existed. D'oh. Thank you very much!